# when :hover li tag why the border cause moving object

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 body {
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
 }
 ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 500px;
   height: 150px;
   background-color: gray;
 }
 ul li {
   display: inline-block;
   -webkit-transition: all0.4s ease-in-out;
 }
 ul li:hover {
   background-color: green;
   border: solid 2px red;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should attempt to make your code more legible if you want an answer. Look at the markdown help for more information.

Comment: Its quite simple. Objects moves because you have specified border only when objects hovered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a transparent border in normal state:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: gray;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  border: solid 2px transparent
}
ul li:hover {
  background-color: green;
  border: solid 2px red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use padding on the before, then remove on hover - see example below:

```css
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 body {
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
 }
 ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 500px;
   height: 150px;
   background-color: gray;
 }
 ul li {
   display: inline-block;
   -webkit-transition: all0.4s ease-in-out;
   padding:2px;
 }
 ul li:hover {
   background-color: green;
   border: solid 2px red;
   padding:0;
 }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```